# Prove that there exists a solution to $P(x) = \sin^2(x)$ when $P(x)$ is a polynomial with at least one non integer multiple of pi zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

What I am trying to prove: Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with $P(0) > 0$ and suppose $P(x)$ has at least one real zero which is not an integer multiple of $\pi$. Prove that there exists a solution to $P(x) = \sin^2(x)$.

I started out assuming $P(x) = a_kx^k + a_{k-1}(x^k-1) + \dots$

Then I saw that $P(x) = x^k(a_k + (1/x)a_{k-1} + \dots)$

I think I assume that $x^k$ is my one real zero. I got stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
Let $y \neq n\pi$ be the zero of $P(x)$. $f(x) = P(x) - \sin^2(x)$ and note that $f(0) > 0$ while $f(y) < 0$. Use continuity of $f$ and the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: So since f(y) < 0 < f(0) there exist an x where f(x) = 0? Is that correct?

Comment: but doesn't that imply that y<0?

Comment: @Goose719 yes, your logic is correct; no - there are no implications about $y>0$ or $y<0$.